# javascript regex negation detect Url NOT containing given domain

Tags: javascript, regex-negation

I need to check some html files and extract the urls that are not referred to 2 websites

after many tests I got this

```
/(http|https)?:?(\/\/)\w*\.*\-*[^(mysite.com)]\w*\.?\S*/igm
```

that works not bad.. but not perfectly:

for example, as can see [HERE on regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3dd9r)  it matches

> // End

but not

> www.demo.com

while should be the countrary, but adding a `?` after `(\/\/)` it becomes an unusful "catch all"

and if url has a `"` at beginning and at the end, and this clearly happens frequently
does not grab starting `"` (correctly) but grab ending one (wrong)

finally it should not match also `theothermysite.net` but do well understood how to handle OR with Negation :-(

can help please?

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/jP1jH8/4)?

```
/((http|https):(\/\/)|www\.)\w*\.*\-*[^(mysite.com)(theothermysite.net)]\w*\.?[^\s\t\r\n\"]*/igm
```

I just added a "or www", replaced `\S` with its components plus `\"` and added another atomic group to the negation like you already did with `mysite.com`